# 任意のバッファに移動する方法

Tags: emacs

縦横に沢山のウィンドウを開いている状態で、C-x oでウィンドウを渡り歩く際、行きたいウィンドウにたどり着くまで何度もC-x oするのが面倒に感じる事があります。

そこで以下の様な機能があれば・・・と夢想するのですが、実現しているelispはあるでしょうか？

1. 何らかのキーバインドで今いるウィンドウのモードラインをハイライトする
2. 何らかのキーバインド(Diredのnやpみたいに)で他のウィンドウのモードラインにハイライトが次々に切り替わる
3. 何らかのキーバインド(Diredのfみたいに)でハイライトされたウィンドウに移動したことになる。またはC-gで(1)以前の状態に復帰する

Answer (score 4):

以下のような設定を `.emacs` に追加してはどうでしょうか

```
;; (1) モードラインの色を変更する
(set-face-background 'mode-line "black")
(set-face-foreground 'mode-line "gray95")
;; (2) Shift+←→↑↓ でウィンドウ移動
(windmove-default-keybindings)
(setq windmove-wrap-around t) ; 端から端へ移動できるように
```

1. アクティブなバッファのモードラインが黒く強調されます。
   配色は `M-x list-colors-display` などを参考にしてお好みで変更してください。
2. ウィンドウ移動に関する機能は、組み込みライブラリの `windmove` が利用できます。
   デフォルトでは<kbd>Shift+←</kbd> <kbd>Shift+→</kbd><kbd>Shift+↑</kbd> <kbd>Shift+↓</kbd> が移動用のキーとして割り当てられます。
   詳しい解説や設定方法は EmacsWiki を参考にしてください。
   https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove